How to search a value from one dictionary into the second dictionary and add the matched value's key:value pair into new dictionary
I have updated the question as it was not clear earlier -
I have two dictionaries dictionary A<string, List<string>> and dictionary B<string, List<string>>, and want to iterate all the "value" from dictionary A into dictionary B.
If the value is found in dictionary B, the respective key:value pair will be saved in dictionary matchFound<string, List<string>>
If the value is NOT found in dictionary B, the respective key:value pair will be saved in dictionary noMatchFound<string, List<string>>
Dictionary<string, List<string>> A = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// below key:value are stored in dictionary A
A.Add("path1",new List<string> {"value1","value2","value3"});
A.Add("path2",new List<string> {"value4","value5","value6"});
A.Add("path3",new List<string> {"value7","value1","value4"}); //the values can get repeated 

Dictionary<string, List<string>> B = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// below key:value are stored in dictionary B
B.Add("path4",new List<string> {"value11","value2","value3"});
B.Add("path5",new List<string> {"value4","value51","value61"});
B.Add("path6",new List<string> {"value71","value1","value4"}); //the values can get repeated 

Dictionary<string, List<string>> matchFound = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> noMatchFound = new Dictionary<string, string>();

All the values present in dictionary A should be searched in dictionary B.
For example, value2 from dictionary A will be searched in dictionary B. If it is found in dictionary B, then the key:value pair i.e. path1:value2 will be stored in dictionary matchFound.
Also, value3 from dictionary A will be searched in dictionary B. Since it is present in dictionary B, the matchFound dictionary will look like -
Key: "path1"
Value:{"value2","value3"})
Similarly, value7 from dictionary A will be searched in dictionary B. value7 is not present in dictionary B, then the key: value pair i.e. path3:value7 will be stored in dictionary noMatchFound
matchFound and noMatchFound are Dictionary<string, List<string>>, because there will be cases where the key(pathX) can be same and that is the reason we have to define the dictionary with <string, List>

Since your "values" are List<T> and those are reference types, ContainsValue isn't going to find a match based on your example code. Do all values in List A need to match List B for it to pass your condition?

If you are trying to compare two sequences you may want to refer to this: determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq

Please provide sample data along with the expected behaviour with that value. Your description is quite vague at the moment, so it's hard to give you a good answer.

You don't want to match the key with B before you check the value?

No, key is not very important here. I want to match the values present in dictionary B.
Also it is not mandatory that the the complete List should be same. If any of the string present in List is present under dictionary B' List , then it is considered as matched and respective key:value pair will be added in dictionary <string, string>

In your example, the Dictionary value is a List<T>, which is a reference type. This is the problem. If you instead used a value type, your example will work perfectly fine.
ContainsValue internally calls GetHashCode and if the hash codes are equal than it calls Equals.
And since List<T> is reference type and reference type equality only checks whether the pointers are the same, which is true only if it is the same instance, than Equals will return false. Note it’s actually not called since GetHashCode returns different hashes in this case.
I propose these solutions based on what is your desired behaviour.
If you don’t care about the order in which the elements were added and how many times one element was added, which I suppose is what you would like, I recommend to use HashSet<T>. The code than looks like this.

Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> A = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
// Key:Values are stored in dictionary A
A.Add(..,..);
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> B = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
// Key:Values are stored in dictionary B
B.Add(..,..);

Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> C = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
foreach (var item in A)
{
   if (B.Values.Any(value => item.Value.SetEquals(value)))
   {
      C.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
   }
}


The method SetEquals checks whether the sets contain the same elements.
If on the other hand you care about the order in which you added the elements and their count, you can use the solution proposed by Mason A.

ContainsValue does an equality check. List is a reference type, and the lists used in dictionary A and B are not the same List. You can use SequenceEqual here to solve this problem:
     Dictionary<string, List<string>> A = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
     // Key:Values are stored in dictionary A
     A.Add(..,..)
     Dictionary<string, List<string>> B = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
     // Key:Values are stored in dictionary B
     B.Add(..,..)

     Dictionary<string, List<string>> C = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
     foreach (var item in A)
     {
        if(B.Values.Any(x => item.Value.SequenceEqual(x)))
        {
           C.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
     }

One Problem that you might notice here, is that you are adding multiple copies of the same key here. This is a separate problem that can be solved by using a different data structure or by adding a unique key.
